# How to normilize rotation to zero

Tags: php, math, geometry

I have a rotated rectangle on a 2d surface

[image]

Known values are:

- x,y (upper left corner)
- width/height of rectangle
- rotation

How can I rotate the rectangle back to zero with the point of origin being the center of the rectangle...

... and then get the new x,y values of the upper left rectangle corner?

[image]

example php function:

```
    function getPositionWithoutRotation(
        float $rotation,
        float $x,
        float $y,
        float $width,
        float $height
    ) {
        $angleRadian = ($rotation * pi()) / 180;

        $xRelativeToCenter = ($width / 2) * cos($angleRadian) - ($height / 2) * sin($angleRadian);
        $yRelativeToCenter = ($width / 2) * sin($angleRadian) + ($height / 2) * cos($angleRadian);

        $cx = $x - $xRelativeToCenter;
        $cy = $y - $yRelativeToCenter;

        $x0 = $cx + ($width / 2);
        $y0 = $cy + ($height / 2);

        return [
            'x0' => $x0,
            'y0' => $y0,
        ];
    }
```

result:

[image]

data:

```
x = 453
y = 244
w = 139
h = 139
rotation = 16

angleRadian = 0.27925268031909

xRelativeToCenter = 47.650891638432
yRelativeToCenter = 85.964484096995

cx = 405.34910836157
cy = 158.03551590301

x0 = 474.84910836157
y0 = 227.53551590301
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: rechecked signs for left top corner

Essentially you need to determine rectangle (and rotation) center.

Let half-width of rectangle is `w`, half-height is `h`. So corner coordinates **relative to center** after rotation by angle `fi` are

```
x' =  -w * cos(fi) - h * sin(fi)
y' =  -w * sin(fi) + h * cos(fi)
```

and center is

```
 cx = x - x'
 cy = y - y'
```

And corner coordinates without rotation:

```
x0 = cx - w
y0 = cy + h
```

Python code:

```
import math
def getPositionWithoutRotation(rotation, x, y, width, height):
    angleRadian = (rotation * math.pi) / 180

    xRelativeToCenter = - (width / 2) * math.cos(angleRadian) - (height / 2) * math.sin(angleRadian)
    yRelativeToCenter = -(width / 2) * math.sin(angleRadian) + (height / 2) * math.cos(angleRadian)

    cx = x - xRelativeToCenter
    cy = y - yRelativeToCenter

    x0 = cx - (width / 2)
    y0 = cy + (height / 2)

    return x0, y0

print(getPositionWithoutRotation(-30, -0.37, 1.37, 2, 2))
print(getPositionWithoutRotation(16, 453, 244, 139, 139))

(-1.0039745962155613, 1.0039745962155615)  //OK
(469.4644840969946, 265.84910836156826)    // ????
```

Comment: actually the center part with the double equal signs is a bit confusing.
can the center equation be simplified to single equal signs?

Comment: I just subsituted x' from the first equation, so `cx =  x - x` and `cx =  x - (w * cos(fi) - h * sin(fi))` are the same

Comment: i am not sure what im doing wrong but im not getting the result i wanted.
[link](https://i.imgur.com/4iticEJ.jpg)

Comment: Could you show example input data and code used. I might make mistake in signs (depends on coordinate system)

Comment: I added a code example and result example in the question

Comment: Yes, my mistake with signs. Check correction  with your data

Comment: so xRelativeToCenter and yRelativeToCenter should be negative values?

Comment: the rotation parameter is the current rotation of the rectangle? not the zero rotation  ?

Comment: It depends on coordinate system. In my first example I used mathematical system with OX to right, OY to top, positive rotation - counterclockwise. Here left top angle has negative shift by x and positive by y (relative to center)